# What is the complexity of this algorithm (search twice integer equals in an array)

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a question, what is the complexity of this alogirthm ?

```
def search(t):
    i = 0;
    find = False
    while (not(find) and i < len(t)) :
        j = i + 1
        while (not(find) and j < len(t)) :
            if (t[j] == t[i]) :
                find = True
            j += 1
        i += 1
    return find
```

Thanks

Comment: if you want n log n use merge sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `t` is a list, it's quadratic (`O(n^2)`, where `n` is the length of the list).

You know it is because it iterates through `t` (first while loop), and in each of these iterations, it iterates through `t` again. Which means it iterates through `len(t)` elements, `len(t)` times. Therefore, `O(len(t)**2)`.

You can bring the complexity of that algorithm down to `O(len(t))` and exactly one line of code by using the appropriate data structure:

```
def search(t):
    return (len(set(t)) != len(t))
```

For more info about how sets work, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: `t`  can be an iterable that supports indexing

Comment: Yeah, it needs to support random indexing in `O(1)` time. If it's actually a *linked* list (which Python lists are *not*), the algorithm becomes `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best case complexity is O(1), as the search may succeed immediately.

The worst case complexity is O(N²), achieved in case the search fails (there are (N-1)+(N-2)+...+2+1 comparisons made, i.e. N(N-1)/2 in total).

The average case can be estimated as follows: assuming that the array contains K entries that are not unique and are spread uniformly, the first of these is located after N/K elements on average, so the outer loop will run N/K times, with a cost of (N-1)+(N-2)+....+(N-N/K) comparisons. In the last iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run about 2N/K times.

Roughly, the expected time is O(N²/K).